# Identify diode marked CD

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, identification, tvs

Diode that needs identification. It is from a power board for a xenon lamp. I could not identify it at all. I referred to the STM site as well but could not find anything. Could you please help?

[image: photo of component]

Comment: Although there is a answer informing to be a “Transil” diode, that is a kind of overvoltage protection/clamping diode, a Xenon lamp application typically would not need such protection, so the description may mean other component too. It could be identified with more safety if you could post more photos for the PCB surroundings for this diode.

Answer (score 4):

It's a 3.3V low-voltage transil ([SMLVT3V3](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/smlvt3v3.pdf)) from ST.

Comment: I saw your link, but doesn’t make sense to me why such 3.3V overvoltage protection diode would be used in a Xenon Lamp circuit. Without more information about the circuit, I would think  such application would use/need a fast switching and/or high voltage rectifier diode.